# Qt c++ Does my program use static or dynamic linking?

Tags: c++, qt, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Sorry about this probably stupid question - I don`t know much about linking :

I use Qt QtCreator to program a GUI in C++ in a program that existed before where  I had to adapt it.  Now my Question is : **How do I know whether the program uses static or dynamic linking?**

When I install the program I wrote on another device I find a list of the executable(s) plus 5 dlls ( libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll, libxml2.dll, mingwm10.dll, QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll)

In my pro-File I have an entry  CONFIG += qaxcontainer and another entry where I do link libxml dynamically .

Does this mean all is linked dynamically?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your program requires the `.dll` file in order to run, it means that it is dynamically linked.
Static libraries are `.lib` (on Windows) and are embedded directly in the executable file.

Comment: That's very misleading; a .lib file can be an "import library," used to implicitly link against a .dll. For more information [see this article on MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx)